# Compactness and Hausdorff property on quotient topology from $R_{std}$

Tags: general-topology

Let $\sim$ be the equivalence relation on $\mathbb{R}$ defined by $x \sim y$ if and only if $x-y \in \mathbb{Z}$ and $\pi: \mathbb{R}_{s t d} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}_{s t d} / \sim, \pi(x)=[x]$ be the quotient map.

I want to show that $\mathbb{R}_{s t d} / \sim$ is compact and Hausdorff.

It is not hard to see that $\mathbb{R}_{s t d} / \sim$ is $$\{[r]| r\in [0,1)\}$$

without defining any map to any ambient space I want to show it is compact and Hausdorff.

I thought that if I can create equivalent quotient topology from some compact set and if I can show a map between them which is a quotient map the the desired space $\mathbb{R}_{s t d} / \sim$ would be automatically compact, since it would be compact image under continuous map. However I can't be sure about the quotient space would have the same topology.

Now consider $[0,1]$

define a relation, $x\sim y$ iff $x=0,y=1$

So $[0,1]/\sim=\{[x] | x\in [0,1) \}$

$$--------$$

I wonder how to show compactness and Hausdorff-ness for the question more naturally or properly?

Comment: Can you prove that it is homeomorphic to $S^1$?  If so, done.  (This is not terribly hard from the universal property of the quotient map.)

Answer (score -1):

As for the Hausdorff property: Take distinct points $[x],[y] \in \mathbb{R}/\sim$. Then it suffices to consider the points $x := \pi^{-1}([x]) \cap [0,1) \in \mathbb{R}$ and $y:= \pi^{-1}([y]) \cap [0,1) \in \mathbb{R}$. Then, because $\mathbb{R}$ is Hausdorff, we find $U_x := (x-\varepsilon_x,x+\varepsilon_x) \ni x$ and $U_y := (y-\varepsilon_y,y+\varepsilon_y)\ni y$, where $\varepsilon_x,\varepsilon_y >0$, such that $U_x \cap U_y =\emptyset$. Then it follows that $[x] \in \pi(U_x)$, $[y] \in \pi(U_y)$ and $\pi(U_x) \cap \pi(U_y) = \emptyset$. Moreover, $\pi(U_x)$ is indeed open by the quotient topology, since
$$
\pi^{-1}(\pi(U_x)) = \bigcup_{k\in\mathbb{Z}}(x-\varepsilon_x+k,x+\varepsilon_x+k).
$$
The same goes for $\pi(U_y)$.

I hope this was helpful!

Comment: Although the set of points $[0, 1) \subset \mathbb{R}$ gives a representative of every point in the quotient, the quotient doesn't have the topology of the half-open interval.

Comment: @SammyBlack You're right, that's what I was missing. Thank you!